# Adding items to JtextArea and updating current balance

Tags: java, jbutton, jtextfield, jtextarea, jradiobutton

I am programming a GUI (Bank Account). I have done the necessary frames, but facing problems in adding information in the JTextArea. I have tried many different ways but still unsuccessful.

When I select a radio button, for example "Savings or Current", the other panels will be visible. And there in the a/c TextField i will input the ID and name in the two TextField. After that I have to select another RadioButton either Deposit or Withdraw and then need to input, how much balance to deposit and withdraw.

And after inputting all the information I need to click the submit button. When I click submit, All the information should display in the JTextArea, and wherever I deposit or withdraw, it should update the information. And this is where I am facing the problem, I have tired many different ways, but failed.....Please help

Please see my coding below:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class BankAccount implements ActionListener,ItemListener
    {
        private String id;
        private double balance;
        private String name;
        private double withdraw;
        private double deposit;

        public BankAccount(String id, double balance, String name, double withdraw, double deposit)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.name = name;
            this.withdraw = withdraw;
            this.deposit = deposit;
        }

        public void deposit(double sum)
        {
            this.balance = this.balance + sum;
        }

        public void withdraw(double sum)
        {
            this.balance = this.balance - sum;
        }

        public String getId()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

        public double getBalance()
        {
            return this.balance;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public double getWithdraw()
        {
            return this.withdraw;
        }


            DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            JList list = new JList(listModel);
            FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lexus Bank");
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p4 = new JPanel();

            JRadioButton a = new JRadioButton("Savings");
            JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton("Current");
            JRadioButton c = new JRadioButton("Deposit");
            JRadioButton d = new JRadioButton("withdraw");

            JLabel l1 = new JLabel("A/C No:");
            JLabel l2 = new JLabel("A/C Name:");
            JTextField accID = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField accName = new JTextField(10);

            JLabel l3 = new JLabel();
            JLabel l4 = new JLabel();
            JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Amount: " );
            JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Current \n Amount: ");
            JLabel l7 = new JLabel();
            JTextField amount = new JTextField(10);
            JButton button = new JButton("Submit");

            JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10,30);              


        public BankAccount() 
        {
            //Setting values for JFrame
            frame.setSize(800,600);
            frame.add(p);
            frame.add(p2);
            frame.add(p3);
            frame.add(p4);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Adding the buttons in group
            group.add(a);
            group.add(b);
            group.add(c);
            group.add(d);

            //Setting value for panel 1
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(flow);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));     
            p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
            p.add(a);
            p.add(b);
            p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),"A/C Type"));

            //Setting value for panel 2
            p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
            p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
            p2.add(l1);
            p2.add(accID);
            p2.add(l2);
            p2.add(accName);
            p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),"Account Details")); 
            p2.setVisible(false);

            //Setting value for panel 3
            p3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,150));
            p3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            p3.add(l3);
            p3.add(c);
            p3.add(l4);
            p3.add(d);
            p3.add(l5);

            p3.add(amount);
            p3.add(button);
            p3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),"Transaction"));
            p3.add(l6);
            p3.setVisible(false);

            //Setting value for panel 4
            p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
            p4.add(area);
            p4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),"Transaction History"));
            p4.setVisible(false);

            //Creating Actions
             a.addItemListener(this);
             b.addItemListener(this);
             c.addActionListener(this);
             d.addActionListener(this);

             button.addActionListener(this);

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            Object source = e.getSource();
            if(source == button)
            {
                if(c.isSelected())
                {
                    String item = area.getText();

                    listModel.addElement(item);
                }

            }       
        }


        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if(source == a)
            {
                p2.setVisible(true);
                p3.setVisible(true);
                p4.setVisible(true);
            }
            if(source == b)
            {
                p2.setVisible(true);
                p3.setVisible(true);
                p4.setVisible(true);
            }


        }


    } 

//Driver Class to run the program
public class BankAccount_Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        BankAccount Test = new BankAccount();
    }


}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you at all setting the text for the JTextArea?

Comment: A JTable would be more appropriate to use instead of a JText area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take my advice use the concept of OOP by separating the classes in to two classes

1. Accounts
2. Bank (main class)

by this way you have a lot of accounts in your program and each account have it's information saved in the object.

```
class Accounts{
private String id;
    private double balance;
    private String name;
    private double withdraw;
    private double deposit;
    //parametric Constructor
    public Accounts(String id,String name, double balance,double withdraw,double deposit){
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        setBalance(balance);
        setWithdraw(withdraw);
        setDeposit(deposit);
    }
   //Default Construcor:
   //Highly recommended having it because you have a parametric constructor
   public Accounts(){
    //...
   }

/*
Don't forget setters and Getter
........ 
*/

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "ID: "+getId()+"\n"
                +"Name: "+getName()+"\n"
                +"Balance: "+getBalance()+"\n"
                +"Withdraw: "+getWithdraw()+"\n"
                +"Deposit: "+getDeposit()+"\n";
    }
}
```

And this will be your *Main* class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Bank {
    private List<Accounts> list ;
    private JButton submit;
    //default Constructor
    public Bank(){
        list = new ArrayList<Accounts>();
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit .addActionListener(this);
        /*
        will be alot of code if I create the whole frame 
        but suppose you have created your frame */
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
      if(ev.getSource()==submit){
         Accounts ac = new Accounts(); 
         ac.setId("id.getText()");
         ac.setName("name.getText()");
        //...
        textArea.setText(ac.toString());//see it's easy 
        list.add(ac);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, I am trying your one, lets hope everything turns up fine :-D

Comment: Bro its giving an "error: constructor Account in class Account cannot be applied to given types;" 
Account cannot be applied to given types;
      Account acnt = new Account();
                     
  required: String,double,String,double,double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
error: cannot find symbol
      acnt.setId("id.getText()");
          
  symbol:   method setId(String)
  location: variable acnt of type Account
C:\Users\Sajid\Documents\Bank.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
   acnt.setName("name.getText()");
       
  


3 errors

Comment: @user2448774 : Yes, my mistake I forget create a default constructor in `Account` class. Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the JTextArea public and call `.setText()` when you want to change the text.

```
public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
```

and later, you can add a method such as:

```
public void setText() {

    textArea.setText("Type something here...");
}
```

Comment: Is it something, that I need to set the text first and then call upon the method getText() to display

Comment: @user2448774 `getText()` would return what is in the text field, `setText()` would set it. You shouldn't need to call `getText()` to display it.

Comment: ohhhh!...let me try it out